# Mobile dongle and wifi connection not work properly in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, internet, usb-modem

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 version to a new laptop (Asus X556U). But I am unable to connect wifi connection to update other software(even my mobile dongle). Here in menu bar "Enable wifi" option also not show. Also, i tried to add the connection for both wifi and mobile dongle.Without the internet connection, i can not update other software including graphic drivers. Can anyone help me?.

Comment: I used ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso file

Comment: Where you connected to the internet when installing Ubuntu?

Comment: I did not connect any network. I installed without internet